# Retrieving and playing sound from a BLOB stream (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, audio

I am trying to play a sound (WAV format) from a BLOB stream.

Here's the raw string:

[image]

I am currently using my library to retrieve data from MySQL.
Nevertheless, here's how did it:

```
// How I did it
byte[] byteArray = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(row["data"].ToString());
// debug only
Console.WriteLine(byteArray.Length + " : " + row["data"].ToString());
// Here's the part when I'm trying to play the sound
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms);
    player.Load();
    player.Play();
}
```

Did I miss something?
If you have other approach to do this, please drop below, I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is your problem? Any messages? Bad sound?

Comment: what is row["data'] for type? Did you followed [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html).

Comment: @rene This is the retrieved string value processed by a library I'm using.

This URL from you has been a great help:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html I'll try this one and will get back here soon

Thanks!

Comment: @DrKoch I'll try Rene's reference. Thanks

Comment: @AllenLinatoc if you fixed it please post an answer

Comment: I'm having another problem: "How do I get the size of the Blob stream in Bytes?". Of course, it is more secure and guaranteed to get the size of the BLOB stream from its actual size rather than just storing its size in a field. Thanks in advance